# linux expect sudo script treat command and argument as a command

Tags: linux, expect, sudo

I want to write an expect script to execute command with arguments, I use $argv as command and arguments to spawn, but unfortunately it seems that expect treat the whole command and arguments as the command. For example, code as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect --


set psw 123456

set timeout  360
spawn  /usr/bin/sudo $argv
expect {
             "*password*" {send "$psw\n"; exp_continue;}
             timeout { exec kill -9 [exp_pid]; close; }
    }
```

if I execute *expect sudo.ext crontab -l* , then some error will occur:

```
spawn /usr/bin/sudo crontab -l
[sudo] password for jadd: 
sudo: crontab -l: command not found
```

what should I do to make the script treats *crontab -l*  not as the whole command?

### -----------------------------------------------------------------

update for answer:
the script runs on centos 6.5 x64, and tcl version 8.5.7
so as Dinesh answered:

```
eval spawn  /usr/bin/sudo $argv
```

or

`spawn  /usr/bin/sudo {*}$argv`

both works

Comment: This might be a question for linux.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `Tcl`  version >= 8.5, then you can use Argument expansion `{*}`.

```
spawn /usr/bin/sudo {*}$argv
```

Else,

```
eval spawn /usr/bin/sudo $argv
```

Comment: The "magic" is that `$argv` is a **list**, so you are passing the list *as a single argument* to sudo. You need to pass *each element* of the argv list as a separate argument to sudo. `{*}` does this, as does `eval`